# proxy servers and sensitive data security

Tags: proxy, privacy

I work in a company and they set up a proxy (**DansGuardian**) and I am afraid that they know all my sensitive data like emails and password because they know all website that I visit and I want to know that if they can cache or store all my sensitive data

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without the proxy, it would always be possible that someone in your company has access to all the unencrypted data sent.

Always encrypt, use SSL correctly.

http://techtips.salon.com/use-ssl-encryption-10163.html

http://lifehacker.com/5745086/why-should-i-care-about-https-on-facebook-or-other-web-sites

Comment: you mean that if I login to my email account they will know my email and password

Comment: No, they _could_. Unencrypted network traffic is not safe at all.